# Divergence and curl of implicitly defined vector field

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Find the divergence and curl of the vector field $\bf F$$=r^5\bf a$$+2r^3(\bf a\cdot r)r$, where $\bf a$ is a constant vector and $r=|\bf r|$.

My thought was to let $\bf r$$=(r_1,r_2,\cdots r_n)$, so that $r=(r_1^2+\cdots +r_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\bf a$$=(a_1,\cdots a_n)$. But with this method I'm not sure at all how to find the required result. Any tips?

Comment: The divergence is $\partial_i(r^5a_i+2r^3a_jr_jr_i)$; the curl's $i$th entry is $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(r^5a_k+2r^3a_lr_lr_k)$. To evaluate these, keep using the product rule, together with$$\partial_ir_j=\delta_{ij},\,\partial_if(r)=\frac{f^\prime(r)}{2r}\partial_i\underbrace{r^2}_{r_jr_j}=\frac{f^\prime(r)}{r}r_i.$$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for this! How do we calculate this though??

Comment: Edit an effort to use my tips into your question so it's clearer which part you're asking about.